# How to add extra row with insert into table select from table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: table_1 contains a post and table_2 contains all users mapped to post. now I would like to insert post into table1 and I will get a post_id, then I will insert all users who are mapped to post with user_id and post_id.

```
 insert into `post_users_map` (`post_id`,`user_id`,`is_owner`)
 select '12345', `user_id`, '0' from `users`
 where username in ("A","B","C")
```

Now I would like to insert `("12345",'123',1)` as another row along with select results.

Any suggestion is appreciated and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How about UNION?

Comment: Thannk you @Strawberry, UNION worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another insert with values after the insert from a select.

```
insert into `post_users_map` (`post_id`,`user_id`,`is_owner`) 
select 12345, user_id, 0
from `users` 
where username in ('A','B','C');

insert into `post_users_map` (`post_id`,`user_id`,`is_owner`) values 
(12345, 123, 1);
```

Also, `values` allows to include more tupples in the same `insert`.

```
insert into `post_users_map` (`post_id`,`user_id`,`is_owner`) values 
(12345, 124, 1),
(12345, 125, 1),
(12345, 126, 1);
```

Or you could use a UNION ALL to insert user_id's from 2 select's with a different is_owner.

```
insert into `post_users_map` (`post_id`,`user_id`,`is_owner`) 
select 12345, user_id, 0
from `users` 
where username in ('A','B','C')
UNION ALL
select 12345, user_id, 1
from `users` 
where username in ('D');
```

Answer (score 2):

just  use union for add the select

```
insert into `post_users_map` (`post_id`,`user_id`,`is_owner`) 
select '12345', `user_id`, '0' 
from `users` where username in ("A","B","C")
UNION 
select '12345', '123, '1'
```